# Как сделать связь между clickhouse и apache?

Tags: php, ubuntu, api, clickhouse

**Здравствуйте, уважаемые.**

Недавно сел изучать php и clickhouse. Поставил себе Ubuntu, на ней развернул apache 2 и php8.0. И столкнулся с проблемой, что apache 2 не хочет использовать код для clickhouse.

Код в phpstorm выводит результат, в то время как, если я зайду через браузер на localhost мне выведется пустой экран, хотя в файле index.php указано, что нужно вывести информацию из базы данных clickhouse.

**config.php**

```
<?php

require_once('/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php');

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('DATABASE', 'Intelect');
define('PORT', '8123');
define('USER', 'default');
define('PASSWORD', '1234');

$client = new ClickHouseDB\Client([
    'host' => HOST,
    'username' => USER,
    'password' => PASSWORD,
    'port'=>PORT,
]);

$client->database(DATABASE);

if(!$client->ping()) echo  "Ошибка подключения!";

echo "Connected!" . "\n";
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-type: json/application');
require 'config.php';

$resultArray = [];
try{
    $result = $client->select('SELECT * FROM main');
    foreach ($result as $row){
        $resultArray[] = $row;
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }
}
catch (Exception $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

**Результат в phpstorm**
[image: Результат в phpstorm]

**Результат в браузере**

*звучание сверчков*

Прошу помощи, так как не знаю, как решить эту проблему. Используемые версии:

Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)

PHP 8.0.28

модуль для соединение clickhouse и php:

8bitov/clickhouse-php-client

Comment: Обновление!

Все действия до 
require 'config.php';

Выполняются. Из-за этого мне кажется, что Apache не воспринимает clickhouse client или что-то в этом роде.